# How to render two files from a single markdown

Tags: jekyll

I have a collection of markdown files and I would like to render in two different set of files using two different layout files when building the page:

– html files for the website
– xml files

Is it possible to do this? It seems that a markdown file can be only parsed once. Any suggestions? Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of having a markdown file that points to a layout file, you're going to need two pages that point to the markdown post file.

There are a number of ways to point to a post file. I like to use a `where` filter:

```
{% assign post = site.posts | where:"url", include.url | first %}
```

Now that you have a `post`, let's say you have `fileOne.html` that you want to put that post into. Here's how you'd approach that:

```
---
layout:main
---

<h1>Some html here</h1>

{% assign post = site.posts | where:"url", include.url | first %}
{{ post.content }}
```

Then you could do the exact same thing in another file named `fileTwo.html`.

Answer (score 0):

Browse markdown files from files using each layout and use the liquid filter `markdownify` to process the same content in different contexts.

> Markdownify
>
> Convert a Markdown-formatted string into HTML.
>
> `{{ page.content | markdownify }}`

Comment: Many thanks! it is still unclear to me how to render a markdown file using two different layouts. In front matter the layout field can be only one value. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Includes](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/includes/) for this.

Note: You can either store your source Markdown files in the `_includes` folder and include them into others with `include`.
Or you store them directly in the folder where the destination files are and use [`include_relative`](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/includes/#including-files-relative-to-another-file).

I'm showing the first option here.

This is the file whose content will end up in another file:

`/_includes/foo.md`:

```
**bold**

[Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com)
```

And here's the file which includes `foo.md`:

---

a) When it's a Markdown file:

```
---
layout: default
title: blah
---

This is the "destination file" for the include.

{% include foo.md %}
```

---

b) Anything that's not Markdown:
(if you want the Markdown from `foo.md` rendered, you have to do this manually)

```
---
layout: default
title: blah
---

<p>This is the "destination file" for the include.</p>

{% capture tmp %}{% include foo.md %}{% endcapture %}
{{ tmp | markdownify }}
```

---

Result in both cases:

```
<p>This is the "destination file" for the include.</p>

<p><strong>bold</strong></p>

<p><a href="https://stackoverflow.com">Stack Overflow</a></p>
```