# Include markdown file in html file

Tags: html, markdown, jekyll, github-pages, github-flavored-markdown

In Jekyll, I have created a layout file `dev.html` which is already using some other `layout: default` but that is not important.

**dev.html**

```
---
layout: default
title: Developer
---
<div>
{{ want to include page1.md }}
</div>

<div>
{{ want to include page2.md }}
</div>
```

Now, I have those 2 markdown pages which I need to include somehow in dev.html file. How can I do that? I have tried using variable `{{content}}` but that would include both pages at once in the `dev.html` file.

**page1.md**

```
---
layout: dev
---
page1 file content in markdown...
```

**page2.md**

```
---
layout: dev
---
page2 file content in markdown...
```

Comment: You have this tagged [jekyll]. Jekyll has a way to do this (the HTML is a "template" and the Markdown document is a "page". How does Jekyll not work for you?

Comment: I am trying to do that also using variables but no luck yet. I have created layout and in layout I want to use variables to display for example 3 different `.md` files but don't know how to use those variables.

Comment: Ah, that was not clear from you question. Please include more information so we can help you. Don't use a comment, but edit your question.

Comment: Okay I have edited question, hope its clear now.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to render two files from a single markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48713344/how-to-render-two-files-from-a-single-markdown)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, it's not possible to "load" two different pages in a layout file.

Do the pages HAVE to have YAML front-matter?
If not, I have a different solution for you: use Jekyll's [Includes](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/includes/).

The way how includes work is basically this:

- You put some HTML files in the `_includes` folder, for example `foo.html`
- You can include their content into another file like this: `{% include foo.html %}`

The only problem is that by default, includes are supposed to be HTML files. But it's possible to use a Markdown file as an include, and render the Markdown by using Liquid's `markdownify` filter.

Example:

### dev.html

*(regular page, not layout file)*

```
---
layout: default
title: Developer
---
<div>
{% capture p1 %}{% include page1.md %}{% endcapture %}
{{ p1 | markdownify }}
</div>

<div>
{% capture p2 %}{% include page2.md %}{% endcapture %}
{{ p2 | markdownify }}
</div>
```

### page1.md

*(without front-matter)*

```
page1 file content in markdown...
```

### page2.md

*(without front-matter)*

```
page2 file content in markdown...
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do this:

```
---
layout: default
title: Developer
---
<div>
  {% assign sitepages = site.pages | where: "slug", "page1" %}
  {% for p in sitepages %}
    {{ p.content }}
  {% endfor %}
</div>

<div>
  {% assign sitepages = site.pages | where: "slug", "page2" %}
  {% for p in sitepages %}
    {{ p.content }}
  {% endfor %}
</div>
```